# Not remembering first user input

Tags: java

I'm trying to get user input for a employee first and last name however the scanner either doesn't accept a first name or doesn't remember the first name.
main method

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ToyShop {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please select from the following options");
        System.out.println("1. Add new employee");
        System.out.println("2. Add new customer");
        System.out.println("3. Add new product");
        System.out.println("4. Edit employee");
        System.out.println("5. Edit customer");
        System.out.println("6. Edit product");
        System.out.println("7. Add new transaction");
        System.out.println("8. Display all transactions");
        System.out.println("9. Exit");

        int pick = in.nextInt();

        if(pick == 1) {
            //first name input
            System.out.println("What is the employees first name: ");
            String eFirst = in.nextLine();
            Employee e1 = new Employee();
            e1.setFirst(eFirst);
            in.hasNext();
            //last name input
            System.out.println("What is their last name: ");
            String eLast = in.nextLine();
            e1.setLast(eLast);
            in.hasNext();

            System.out.println(e1.toString() + eFirst);
        }

    }

}

employee class
public class Employee extends Person {

    private static int id;
    private String depart;

    public Employee() {
        this.id = 1000;
        this.depart = "";
        Employee.super.setFirst("");
        Employee.super.setLast("");
    }

    public Employee(int id, String depart, String first, String last) {
        super(first, last);
        this.id = id += 1;
        this.depart = depart;
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id += 1;
    }

    /**
     * @return the depart (department)
     */
    public String getDepart() {
        return depart;
    }

    /**
     * @param depart the department to set
     */
    public void setDepart(String depart) {
        this.depart = depart;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + id + "] " + getFirst() + " " + getLast() + ", " + depart;
    }
}
```

when it prints the e1 (employee object 1) toString it will only print out the first name and if I remove the two in.hasNext() lines it will skip the user input for the first name

Comment: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](//stackoverflow.com/q/13102045)

Comment: What is the output you are giving and what is your console output of the ```toString()```? Also, as mentioned, you should read about the ```nextInt()``` vs ```nextLine()``` behaviour in the link shared above

Comment: the toString output is supposed to be getFirst + " " + getLast from the employee class and the console outputs " " + getLast. I have been trying the nextLine methods linked above to no avail, it will either remain the same or switch and print only getFirst and not getLast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that method `nextInt()` doesn't detect newlines (think of the user hitting the enter button) properly like method `nextLine()` does. So you need to add `nextLine()` after that to be able to detect the newline input. Method `hasNext()` isn't necessary since that only returns a boolean depending on the state of the scanner's token.

```
int pick = in.nextInt();
in.nextLine();            //this is what's needed to detect the newline

if(pick == 1) {
    //first name input
    System.out.println("What is the employees first name: ");
    String eFirst = in.nextLine();
    e1.setFirst(eFirst);
    //in.hasNext();           (you don't need this)
    //last name input  
    System.out.println("What is their last name: ");
    String eLast = in.nextLine();
    e1.setLast(eLast);
    //in.hasNext();           (you don't need this)

    System.out.println(e1.toString() + eFirst);
}
```

This will successfully detect input of the number selection, first, and last name.